# read json to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, parsing

I have a data file in json format downloaded from another system.
It can be observed that it contains one row with all the column names as shown as keys in the json string with its values. Metadata for this one row contains another json string.

```
{
  "createdTime": 1625433352096,
  "lastUpdatedTime": 1664815053126,
  "rootId": 5710030000009051,
  "parentId": 0000010904715472,
  "parentExtId": "J802-RFPS-2F-1004",
  "externalId": "J802-RFPS-003FT1004A",
  "name": "J802-RFPS-003FT2224A",
  "description": "113FT1004A, RFP5 CRDE CHG PMP TO TN 1",
  "dataSetId": 4833410000089553,
  "metadata": {
    "Catalog Profile": "16",
    "Cost Center": "TNK7222414",
    "Installation of equipment allowed": "Yes",
    "Location": "112-SCU",
    "Location and Account Assignment": "11223355",
    "PP Work Center": "10000420",
    "Planner Group": "CRD",
    "Plant Section": "CE",
    "SAP Object No": "01649",
    "Single Equipment Installation": "Yes",
    "Type": "I_CVL",
    "Work Center": "9876542"
  },
  "source": "SAP PM",
  "id": 8972234567977
}
```

I am using the following code in python to read it as dataframe.

```
import json 
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

json_file_path = r'D:\asset-897428209692977.json'

# path to file
p = Path(json_file_path)

# read json
with p.open('r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

# create dataframe
df2 = pd.json_normalize(data)
```

The output has one row but the dataframe splits the metadata into multiple columns such as `metadata.planner`, `metadata.PM`, `metadata.ID`......

Is there another way to keep it as one row so that when some keys are missing in certain records, it doesn't find itself missing or removed in this json parsing. Please advise the best approach

Comment: Please edit your tags to use the proper `python` tag rather than the `python-3.x` tag, which is reserved for questions that specifically apply to python 3, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x).

Comment: Try `df2 = pd.DataFrame([data])` instead of `df2 = pd.json_normalize(data)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any direct way to do this in a direct manner. However, you can still include metadata into the database manually, and then add metadata manually as a single column.

```py
metadata = data.pop('metadata')
df2 = pd.json_normalize(data)
df2['metadata'] = [metadata]
```

However I'm not able to test the code on the data you've provided, so I am not sure it'll work without without any issues. Both original and modified versions do return the same error - "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 108 (char 107)" while I'm trying to run them, and I'm not sure why does the error happen.